# Value of type 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor' has no member 'constraint'

Tags: ios-autolayout, swift4.1

in Swift 4.1 and XCode 9.3.1 I am getting this error for code.

```
 if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
    }
```

[image: This] is the error

Also for this following code.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                btn2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btn2.frame.width).isActive = true
                btn2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btn2.frame.height).isActive = true
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
```

I get error like [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

After going through [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutdimension), Changing following code from

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
} else {
}
```

to

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        contentView.topAnchor.constraintEqual(to: topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqual(to: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraintEqual(to: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraintEqual(to: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
    }
```

and this from

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            btn2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btn2.frame.width).isActive = true
            btn2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: btn2.frame.height).isActive = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

to

```
 if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                btn2.widthAnchor.constraintEqual(toConstant: btn2.frame.width).isActive = true
                btn2.heightAnchor.constraintEqual(toConstant: btn2.frame.height).isActive = true
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
```

Worked for me thank you.